# Dell Latitude touchpad not working

Tags: laptop, touchpad, dell-latitude

**The Situation:** About two hours ago, I spilled water on the touchpad of my Dell Latitude. Usually, when this happens, I dry it with a towel and it starts working again. However, this time, it seems to be frozen. Now, I'm not very tech savvy and I have absolutely no idea what happened, so I started searching the internet for solutions.

**The Trials:** One website told me to reset the touchpad, which I did and found that it does not work. Another told me to take the laptop apart and blow-dry it. I am not going to do that. I have also been letting it sit. That does not work, either.

Can someone help me?